# Cannot read property ‘nextOnTargetClick’ error after Hopscotch tour ends/is closed

Tags: javascript, navigation, keyboard, onstart, hopscotch

I am using LinkedIn's Hopscotch framework for a tutorial, and implemented this onStart of the tour to move between tour steps using the left and right arrow keys: [Keyboard support to navigate between steps](https://github.com/linkedin/hopscotch/issues/8)

The function works fine, but when the tour ends or is closed midway, a left and right arrow button press gives this error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘nextOnTargetClick’ of null … at a.nextStep**

It looks to me like the tour's onStart() is always active even after the tour ends.
Any advice on eliminating this error?